# Performance Issue When Using Manipulate

Tags: graphics, performance-tuning, manipulate

Any help would be appreciated!

I've been attempting to manipulate the graphics for time t. We need to have Di set to 11.2, however when it is set to any value greater than .1, we see a great deal of slowdown. Is there anyway to increase performance so that we don't see any slowdown? Adjusting Di affects the "vibration" between the two disks.

```
Clear[qzero];
Clear[Pthzero];
Clear[\[Lambda]];
Clear[Di];

sol = ParametricNDSolve[{q'[t] == Pq[t], 
theta'[t] == Ptheta[t]/q[t]^2, 
Pq'[t] == 
 Ptheta[t]^2/q[t]^3 - 
  2 Di \[Lambda] (1 -  Exp[-\[Lambda] (q[t] - 1)]) Exp[-\[Lambda] (q[t] - 1)], 
Ptheta'[t] == 0, q[0] == qzero, theta[0] == 0, Pq[0] == 0, 
Ptheta[0] == Pthzero}, {Pq, q, theta, Ptheta}, {t, 0, 500}, {PqO, 
thzero, qzero, Pthzero, \[Lambda], Di}];

m1 = 12*(1.99*10^-26);
radius1 = 70;
m2 = 16*(1.99*10^-26);
radius2 = 60;
re = 112.8;
Di = 10;

Manipulate[
  Graphics[{White, 
   Rectangle[{-300, -300}, {300, 300}], {Darker[Red], 
    Disk[{(m2/(m1 + m2))*re*
     Evaluate[q[0, 0, qzero, Pthzero, 2.7965, Di][t] /. sol]*
     Cos[Evaluate[
     theta[0, 0, qzero, Pthzero, 2.7965, Di][t] /. 
     sol]], (m2/(m1 + m2))*re*
   Evaluate[q[0, 0, qzero, Pthzero, 2.7965, Di][t] /. sol]*
   Sin[Evaluate[
     theta[0, 0, qzero, Pthzero, 2.7965, Di][t] /. sol]]}, 
 radius1]}, {Darker[Green], 
Disk[{(m1/(m1 + m2))*re*
   Evaluate[q[0, 0, qzero, Pthzero, 2.7965, Di][t] /. sol]*
   Cos[Evaluate[
      theta[0, 0, qzero, Pthzero, 2.7965, Di][t] /. sol] + 
     Pi], (m1/(m1 + m2))*re*
   Evaluate[q[0, 0, qzero, Pthzero, 2.7965, Di][t] /. sol]*
   Sin[Evaluate[
      theta[0, 0, qzero, Pthzero, 2.7965, Di][t] /. sol] + Pi]}, 
 radius2]}}], {qzero, .5, 
  2}, {Pthzero, -.0445633841, .0445633841}, {t, 0, 500}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

A number of things can be done to improve the responsiveness of `Manipulate` here.  First, do not compute the same quantity more than once; see `q1` and `theta1`.  Second, set `ContinuousAction -> False`, so that calculations are not performed until a `Slider` stops moving.  (See `ContinuousAction` [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ContinuousAction.html).)  Finally, increase the speed of `ParametricNDSolve` itself by eliminating `Ptheta` as a variable, because it is a constant according to `Ptheta'[t] == 0` in your code.  In total, the revised code becomes:

```
Clear[Di];
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{q'[t] == Pq[t], theta'[t] == Pthzero/q[t]^2, 
  Pq'[t] == Pthzero^2/q[t]^3 - 2 Di λ (1 - Exp[-λ (q[t] - 1)]) Exp[-λ (q[t] - 1)], 
  q[0] == qzero, theta[0] == 0, Pq[0] == 0}, {Pq, q, theta}, {t, 0, 500}, 
  {PqO, thzero, qzero, Pthzero, λ, Di}];
m1 = 12*(1.99*10^-26); radius1 = 70; m2 = 16*(1.99*10^-26); radius2 = 60;
  re = 112.8; Di = 10;
Manipulate[ q1 = re*Evaluate[q[0, 0, qzero, Pthzero, 2.7965, Di][t] /. sol[[2]]];
  theta1 = Evaluate[theta[0, 0, qzero, Pthzero, 2.7965, Di][t] /. sol[[3]]]; 
  Graphics[{White, Rectangle[{-300, -300}, {300, 300}],
    {Darker[Red], Disk[{(m2/(m1 + m2))*q1*Cos[theta1], 
      (m2/(m1 + m2))*q1*Sin[theta1]}, radius1]}, 
    {Darker[Green], Disk[{(m1/(m1 + m2))*q1*Cos[theta1 + Pi], 
      (m1/(m1 + m2)) q1*Sin[theta1 + Pi]}, radius2]}}],
  {qzero, .5, 2}, {Pthzero, -.0445633841, .0445633841}, {t, 0, 500}, 
  ContinuousAction -> False]
```

There may be other ways to speed things up, but this seems like a good start.

**Updated** to replace `SynchronousUpdating` by `ContinuousAction`, prompted by comment by Kuba.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take.  First, I'd use `NDSolve` because having the separate `ParametericFunction` solutions seems like the ODE has to be solved for each variable (am I wrong?).  In any case, `NDSolve` seems simple enough since most of the parameters are `Manipulate` variables.  Next, I'd separate the solution of the ODE from drawing the graphics by means of an extra `Dynamic`.  This gives great responsiveness when the `t` slider is moved.  It is still slow when the parameters `qzero` and `Pthzero` are changed.  (See below for further improvements.)

```
Manipulate[
 With[{sol = With[{λ = 2.7965}, 
     First@NDSolve[{
        q'[$t] == Pq[$t], 
        theta'[$t] == Pthzero/q[$t]^2, 
        Pq'[$t] == Pthzero^2/q[$t]^3 - 
          2 Di λ (1 - Exp[-λ (q[$t] - 1)]) Exp[-λ (q[$t] - 1)], 
        q[0] == qzero, theta[0] == 0, Pq[0] == 0},
      {q, theta}, {$t, 0, t}]]},
  Graphics[
   Dynamic[     (* only graphics will be updated when t changes *)
    {White, Rectangle[{-300, -300}, {300, 300}],
     {Darker[Red], 
       Disk[{(m2/(m1 + m2))*re*q[t]*Cos[theta[t]],
             (m2/(m1 + m2))*re*q[t]*Sin[theta[t]]}, radius1]},
     {Darker[Green], 
       Disk[{(m1/(m1 + m2))*re*q[t]*Cos[theta[t] + Pi],
             (m1/(m1 + m2))*re*q[t]*Sin[theta[t] + Pi]}, radius2]}} /. sol],
   Frame -> True]
  ],
 {{qzero, 0.5}, 0.5, 2}, {Pthzero, -.0445633841, .0445633841}, {t, 0, 500}]
```

---

One drawback with `ContinuousAction -> False` is that you cannot monitor what is going on while the parameters change.  Here are some ideas for addressing this.  For large values of `qzero` and `t`, there is no real solution to small delays, as far as I can find.  The delays would be acceptable to me, but I believe that is what the OP is asking to be addressed.

One way to speed things up is to make some parameters change with [`ControlActive`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ControlActive.html). For instance, we can integrate the ODE only up to `t` while the slider is moving.  (Clicking on the slider will evaluate the previous solution at the new value of `t`, so when the slider is released we need to calculate the solution to the end `500`.)

We can speed up `NDSolve` by reducing `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`, but the computed solutions in the cases where the increase in speed in noticeable are rather inaccurate.  To get a good speed up they need to be reduced to less than half the default (~8). With such a setting, when the slider is released and the settings restored to `Automatic`, the disks jump a little, so you are still not able to track the behavior very accurately.

Example call of `NDSolve`.

```
NDSolve[<ODE above>, {q, theta},
 {$t, 0, ControlActive[t, 500]}, 
 PrecisionGoal -> ControlActive[3, Automatic], 
 AccuracyGoal -> ControlActive[2, Automatic]]
```

---

Finally, I've occasionally encounter underflow and overflow errors at high values of the parameters.  Perhaps integrating out to `500` is unnecessary, at least in a `Manipulate`.  Here is an example of `q[t]` just out to `t == 50` (`` Pthzero = 0.0023999999999999994`, qzero = 1.552 ``):

```
Plot[q[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 50}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]